List git branches between two merges
I have the following git branch structure

features:  C   D    E
          / \ / \  / \
staging : --------------
           \       \
release : --A-------B--

I am trying to get a list of all feature branches between merges A and B, (i.e. C,D,E), is this possible in a generic way without knowing the hashes of A and B, i.e. give me all branches merged into the release branch through the previous merge.
If branches aren't possible are a list of commits possible?

Please note that if the branches have been merged and then deleted (as is common on sites like github) then you can only see the commits and their messages

The list of commits you want seems to just be those reachable from B that are not reachable from A, which you can get with git rev-list B ^A

To list merge commits on the release branch:
git log --oneline --merges --first-parent release 
# or
git rev-list --merges --first-parent release

To list branches that were merged between commits A and B:
git branch --no-merged A --merged B


note: you do not need to specifically use merge commits in the second command.
For example: if you have a tag pointing at the previous version, you can run:
git branch --no-merged v2.3.4 --merged release

to spot all the branches that have been merged into release since that version.
